# how to write requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) with API 31+ in Android-Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

how to write this code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

in APi 31+

with   SuperClass  **ComponentActivity** in jetpackcompose, because with this code not hidden titlebar, used Kotlin

```
class MainActivity:ComponentActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

        setContent {

            SMarketTheme {
                        .........

}
```

Comment: What theme are you using in `AndroidManifest.xml` for the `application` tag or your `activity` tag. Can you please add the `android:theme="..."` attributes from those tags to the question.

Comment: i used default theme, but  it is new type theme API 31+ for jetpack compose projects.----------->@Composable
fun SMarketTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) { val colors = if (darkTheme) {DarkColorPalette } else  LightColorPalette}MaterialTheme(....... )
} . Problems  only with ComponentActivity SuperClas ,  With AppCompactActivity SuperClass no problem , but in Api 31+ is required use  ComponenActivity , because AppCompactActivity is not compatible with api 31+

Comment: I am also using API 31+ (I use 32) and my `Activity` extends `ComponentActivity` and I have no problems with hiding title bars or system bars. A simple way to achieve that is to set the correct parent theme in `AndroidManifest` for your appliaction/activity. For example `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar`. Update your question with your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I think it's a bug, I think the files that manage "themes" are duplicated and conflict, For example  theme declared in "Theme.kt" file conflict with the values/themes.xml file

Solution, modify the values/themes.xml file

```
 <style name="Theme.SMarket" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_700</item>-->
</style>
```

and ignore  Themes.kt

in this way it is not necessary

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```